# My clan participated in the last clan wars, now we are locked in and can’t war with individual clans how can I change that

Tags: clash-of-clans

We participated in clan wars, now we are locked in.  We cannot war clan on clan.  How can I change that

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean [Clan War League](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Clan_War_Leagues). Once a clan enters the queue for a Clan War League, that clan cannot do any other war types. Also, during the sign-up period for the Clan War League, only this Clan War mode is available.

If you don't want to participate in the Clan War League and instead do the regular Clan Wars, then you will have to wait until the sign up period for Clan War League season is over (the sign-up period lasts 2 days, and the Clan War button will revert from the golden icon to the regular one).